# store separate select statements as tables before doing EXCEPT/ JOIN (t-sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using t-sql,

I have two separate select statements. The first one involves nested queries based on parameters passed to the nested query.

Can i use the results of the first select statement as a table to use the "EXCEPT" operator or JOIN operator to connect with the select result set coming from the 2nd select statement in the format:

```
select col1,col2,col3 from tableOne where col3=(nested queries) as table1 
<EXCEPT/JOIN>
select col3,col4,col5 from tableOne where col2=(nested queries) as table2
```

"as table1/2" gives me errors and "EXCEPT" key word, only excepts one column to do the comparison Are there better approaches for this?

Comment: What exactly yo want?

Comment: `EXCEPT key word, only excepts one column to do the comparison` what makes you think that? `EXCEPT` is the reverse operation to `UNION` and does comparisons on whole rows (all columns) consider this statement for example `SELECT 1, 2, 3 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3, 4 EXCEPT (SELECT 1, 4, 3 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3, 4)`

Comment: @JithinShaji I want to know if a select statement can be stored as a table, so that it coould be used in the later part of the query may be for a join. For an example:

Comment: @JithinShaji I want to know if a select statement can be stored as a table, so that it could be used in the later part of the query may be for a join. This is pretty much theory based question.For an example: `(select aa,bb from Table a where cc IN (nestedquery_goes_here)) AS OUTERTABLE   INNER JOIN SECONDTABLE ON OUTERTABLE.aa = SECONDTABLE.yy`

Comment: @DrCopyPaste My issue is that i have a query which has nested queries. At a nested query level i need to get two colmns, but since of the query structure i am unable to get it. The code goes as follows: `Select aa,bb,cc from TABLE1 where aa IN (select ee from TABLE2 where ff=(nestedquesry) EXCEPT select ee from TABLE2 where yy='somevalue')` Actually in the nested level in TABLE2 i need to get two columns like `select ee,gg from TABLE2` but (1) the except needs to check only column 'ee' & (2) The IN clause excepts one columns. So i was planning to have the results of this query as a table &join

Comment: Basically what you seem to want is called a *derived table*: you can use the result of a query as a table. However, mixing `EXCEPT` and `JOIN` as if they were the same kind of operator is confusing as to what you want to do with the result sets. Please provide a better example clarifying what you are trying to do. EXCEPT could likely be used the way you've shown in your example except you'd need to get rid of `as table1` and `as table2`. JOIN, on the other hand, is used very differently, so please elaborate.